# Cassandra: How to get a list of processes?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli, cassandra-0.7

Hello Cassandra Experts,

How can I get a list of processes in Cassandra cluster (similiar to the `show processlist` command of MySQL)?  Im puzzled as to why I cannot find any posts anywhere about this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're trying to somve with this info?

Comment: I simple want to know what the database is doing, what types of reads, updates, loading, etc so that I can correlate this back to the apps/environment in order to troubleshoot any amiss situations.

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking about what this would look like on a cluster distributed over, say, a couple hundred nodes. Millions of queries taking a few millis each, and for each query communicating information about the query to some central point so that a tool can observe it. It seems like that could significantly impact performance.

Comment: I have 12 nodes. Is there any way to see the processlist?  This is really a simple request in all other db platforms.

Comment: It makes sense in other platforms. It might make sense for a distributed database, too, but the issues above make me wonder.

Comment: Distributed or not, DBAs/others need to know that the db is doing.

Comment: Okay. How would you go about implementing it for a distributed database?